# Básico - Java: error: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, lógica

Estou aprendendo POO por Java e este seria o meu primeiro código, fora o clássico hello world kkk.

Quanto tempo compilar ele via bash, o seguinte erro aparece:

aula2.java:12: error: class, interface, or enum expected

package aula2;

^
1 error

Pela minha mínima experiência, o erro seria na linha 12 do código, com o nome "package aula2;", mas não consigo entender qual erro acontece nesta linha...

Segue o código:

```
package aula2;
public class Aula2 {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Caneta c1 = new Caneta();   
    c1.color = "Blue";
    c1.model = "Bic";
}

}

package aula2;
public class Caneta 
{
    String model;
    String color;
        

    void status()
        {

        System.out.print("Uma caneta " + this.color);
        System.out.print("A marca da caneta é " + this.model);
        
        }
}
```

Poderiam me dar uma luz para entender kk?

Agradeço!

Comment: Mas esses são arquivos separados? Declarar o nome do pacote duas vezes no mesmo arquivo é um erro mesmo, além disso, você não pode declarar duas classes públicas no mesmo arquivo, pois cada arquivo só pode exportar uma classe.

Comment: Fiquei na dúvida para te responder, mas acho que é o mesmo arquivo... quanto as classes, não sabia. O vídeo que eu vi mostrou assim. Como ficaria com as mudanças?

Answer (score 0):

Tente executar desta forma:

```
 package aula2;

 public class Aula2 {

        public static class Caneta {

            String model;
            String color;

            public void status() {

                System.out.print("Uma caneta " + this.color + ".");
                System.out.print("A marca da caneta é " + this.model);

            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Caneta c1 = new Aula2.Caneta();
            c1.color = "Blue";
            c1.model = "Bic";

            c1.status();
        }
    }
```

Ou desta:

```
package aula2;

public class Aula2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Caneta c1 = new Caneta();
        c1.color = "Blue";
        c1.model = "Bic";

        c1.status();
    }
}

class Caneta {

    String model;
    String color;

    public void status() {
        System.out.print("Uma caneta " + this.color + ".");
        System.out.print("A marca da caneta é " + this.model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode declarar [pacotes](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_packages.asp) duas vezes no mesmo arquivo. Além disso, [apenas uma classe pública pode ser declarada por arquivo](http://high5devs.com/2015/01/nome-dos-arquivos-e-nome-das-classes-na-linguagem-java/#:%7E:text=Ao%20declarar%20uma%20classe%20p%C3%BAblica,o%20mesmo%20nome%20do%20arquivo.).

Divida sua classe em dois arquivos com a mesma declaração de pacote:

```
// Arquivo Aula2.java
package aula2;

public class Aula2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Caneta c1 = new Caneta();
        c1.color = "Blue";
        c1.model = "Bic";
        c1.status();
    }
}
```

--

```
// Arquivo Caneta.java
package aula2;

public class Caneta {
    String model;
    String color;

    public void status() {
        System.out.print("Uma caneta " + this.color + ".");
        System.out.print("A marca da caneta é " + this.model);
    }
}
```